# TCPDF generated file does not open on ajax call

Tags: php, ajax, tcpdf

Everything work fine if I use this:

```
form name="nnewOBR" id="inewOBR" method="POST" action="targetsample_pdf.php" target="_blank"
```

The data from the form will be saved in the database and the PDF will be opened. But when I use ajax, it will only execute the insertion of data in the database but it will not open the PDF. My ajax statement is as follows:

```
$(function() {
$("#inewOBR").submit(function() {
var datos = $('#inewOBR').serialize();
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "targetsample_pdf.php",
  data: datos,
  success: function(data) {
    alert("Successful");
  }
});
return false;
});
});
```

I would really appreciate your help. Thank you very much.

Comment: if your replacing the current page view with the pdf, there is no point in using ajax

Comment: How will I do it if I would like a notification for the user to either open or not the PDF upon submission of the form? Thanks

Comment: I would add an option in the form, if they select yup, do the pdf thing, if not do something else. If you like have a js popup on form submission- but still pass that value along with the form to the server